# Gazebo doesn't free RAM when deleting a TurtleBot3 model using the /delete_entity service

Tags: gazebo, ros2, turtlebot3, spawn-model, memory

For the needs of my project, I wrote a node in ROS2 that sequentially pauses the simulation in Gazebo, spawns the TurtleBot3 at the desired location, starts the simulation, pauses the simulation, and deletes the model. As soon as the robot model spawns, I intend to collect measurements from the laser to use them later.

Pausing and starting the simulation physics was necessary because, in the case of spawning and deleting the robot while the simulation was running, the code stopped due to the lack of response from the `/delete_enitty` service.

At the moment, the described sequence works, but as the number of subsequent repetitions increases, the RAM usage on my computer increases significantly. The reason is that the Gazebo server (`gzserver`) is allocating more and more memory. It seems as if deleting a model does not free previously used memory.

My question is, is it possible to free this memory somehow? I want to be able to get any (within reason) number of iterations. At the moment, the solution that comes to my mind is to monitor RAM usage and stop my node and restart the simulation.

```
❯ echo $ROS_DISTRO
humble
❯ gazebo --version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
```

Services I use:

- `/spawn_entity`
- `/delete_entity`
- `/pause_physics`
- `/unpause_physics`

All of these services are served by the `gazebo` node, which starts when the simulation is run with:

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_dqn_stage1.launch.py
```

Below is a screenshot showing the memory consumption of the `gzersver` process after over 250 iterations of my node.

[image: RAM usage by gzserver]

Below is my node code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from .utils.entity_service_handler import EntityServiceHandler
from .utils.physics_service_handler import PhysicsServiceHandler


class ScanCollector(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes an instance of the ScanCollector class.
        """

        super().__init__("scan_collector")
        self.get_logger().info("ScanCollector node started.")
        self.__entity_service_handler = EntityServiceHandler(self)
        self.__physics_service_handler = PhysicsServiceHandler(self)

    def spawn_entity(self, x_set: float, y_set: float) -> None:
        """
        Spawns an entity at the specified coordinates.

        Args:
            x_set (float): The x-coordinate of the entity.
            y_set (float): The y-coordinate of the entity.
        """

        self.__entity_service_handler.spawn_entity(x_set, y_set)

    def delete_entity(self) -> None:
        """
        Deletes the entity using the entity service handler.
        """

        self.__entity_service_handler.delete_entity()

    def pause_physics(self) -> None:
        """
        Pauses the physics using the physics service handler.
        """

        self.__physics_service_handler.pause_physics()

    def unpause_physics(self) -> None:
        """
        Unpauses the physics using the physics service handler.
        """

        self.__physics_service_handler.unpause_physics()


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = ScanCollector()
    for i in range(1000):
        print(f"Iteraion {i}")
        node.pause_physics()
        node.spawn_entity(0.0, 0.0)
        node.unpause_physics()
        # Collect laser data
        node.pause_physics()
        node.delete_entity()
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```